# Will old REST API require OAuth 2 from Oct. 1st.

Tags: authentication, facebook-oauth, facebook-rest-api

It's not clear from Facebook's authentication documentation and Dev. Roadmap if the deprecation of some older authorization methods will also include the deprecation of the old REST API authorization method, which is custom.

My application only uses REST API and FQL (through fql.query method).
Do I also have to convert my app to be OAuth 2 by Oct 1st?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you need to convert to OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, Eddy. What's your source to this answer? I couldn't find a definitive answer in the documentation.

Comment: Old REST API / FQL is an api to access fb data/function.
OAuth is for authentication and All fb apps need authentication.  So u need to handle that